# Index not the same between writing and reading excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Here is the problem. I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('excelA.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('excelB.xlsx')

ind = df1['some_col']
cols = df2.columns

# Using index from df1 and columns from df2 create a new df
res_df = pd.DataFrame(index=ind, columns=cols)

# Inserting values from df2 into new df
for c in cols:
    for j in range(len(df2[c])):
        res_df[c].iloc[j] = df2[c].iloc[j]

print(res_df.index) // Index([something, something2, something3 ... ])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
res_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True) 
writer.close()
```

Now when I try to read the file

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', dtype=str)
print(df.index) // RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1000, step=1)
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: can you share a few rows of your data frame?

Comment: While reading excel keep `index_col = some_index`

Comment: @MohammadAthar I just posted my complete code

Comment: @WiLL_K The part of code that reads excel is independent of the code that writes. Is it possible set the index while writing?

Comment: @Ajit Indeed you can `index=False` while writing excel

Comment: @WiLL_K Yes, but that would discard my original index. I want to preserve my index. But right now, the index appears as one of the columns of the dataframe when reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in excel what is column index of index column.

Then use pd.read_excel(''test.xlsx',index_col=[index_in_excel])

Comment: Is it possible to set the index when writing in a way that it reads it as index when reading?

Comment: Index gets written as 1 column. As for Excel there is not concept of Index but pandas there is concept of Index. So you need to handle it in your code while reading it.

Comment: Thanks I just realized that index_col is set to `None` by default. I have set it `0`. There is no other way around it